# Operator 'AND' in the get_posts() function's tax_query terms not working

Tags: taxonomy, get-posts, tax-query

I am trying to get posts that are present in both the taxonomy `terms`. This is the code that didn't work:

```
$args = array(
'post_type'      => 'workshops',
'posts_per_page' => -1,
'fields'         => 'ids',
'tax_query'      => array(
      array(
        'taxonomy' => 'workshop_categories',
        'field'    => 'slug',
        'terms'    => array('crafts', 'jewellery'),
        'operator' => 'AND',
      )
  )
);

$posts = get_posts( $args );
```

However this one works fine:

```
$args = array(
'post_type'      => 'workshops',
'posts_per_page' => -1,
'fields'         => 'ids',
'tax_query'      => array(
    'relation' => 'AND',
    array(
        'taxonomy' => 'workshop_categories',
        'field'    => 'slug',
        'terms'    => 'crafts',
    ),
    array(
        'taxonomy' => 'workshop_categories',
        'field'    => 'slug',
        'terms'    => 'jewellery',
    ),
  ),
 );
$posts = get_posts( $args );
```

I am trying to understand why the first code snippet didn't work using `'operator' => 'AND'`.

Comment: Note that `get_posts` is a wrapper around `WP_Query`, and by only fetching `ids` you might improve the performance of this query, but you've sacrificed cache priming so now every single call to `get_post_meta` or to grab terms will trigger lots of small database queries, likely eliminating any performance gains and reducing performance. If you really need to loop through every single workshop post with those terms you should use 2 nested loops and pagination so that it only holds one page of posts in memory, but can still perform DB fetching optimisations. You'll also want to set post status

Comment: @TomJNowell I don't think I fully understood your comment. Isn't `get_posts()` doing the same thing that you have suggested; i.e. 2 nested loops?

Comment: no it isn't, because you've asked it to fetch _all_ the posts by specifying `-1`, so if your server has 10 million posts but only has space for 1000 posts, then it will give an out of memory error. Likewise it won't print anything until all the posts are fetched from the database then primed which could be a while. `get_posts` still has to construct an array that then contains all of those posts which is the very problem I was pointing out

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `include_children` parameter as `false` to your first example (tested):

```php
$args = array(
    'post_type'      => 'workshops',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'fields'         => 'ids',
    'tax_query'      => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy'         => 'workshop_categories',
            'field'            => 'slug',
            'terms'            => array( 'crafts', 'jewellery' ),
            'operator'         => 'AND',
            'include_children' => false,
        )
    )
);

$posts = get_posts( $args );
```

Unfortunately I can't explain why, but that was necessary for my test to work.

Comment: Yes, that seems to work! In my case, `crafts` is a parent term and `jewellery` is its child term. `include_children => false` doesn't make sense to me too.